# React hooks - setState does not update state properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a event binding from the window object on scroll. It gets properly fired everytime I scroll. Until now everything works fine. But the setNavState function (this is my setState-function) does not update my state properties.

```
export default function TabBar() {
    const [navState, setNavState] = React.useState(
        {
            showNavLogo: true,
            lastScrollPos: 0
        });

    function handleScroll(e: any) {
        const currScrollPos = e.path[1].scrollY;
        const { lastScrollPos, showNavLogo } = navState;

        console.log('currScrollPos: ', currScrollPos); // updates accordingly to the scroll pos
        console.log('lastScrollPos: ', lastScrollPos); // last scroll keeps beeing 0
        if (currScrollPos > lastScrollPos) {
            setNavState({showNavLogo: false, lastScrollPos: currScrollPos});
        } else {
            setNavState({showNavLogo: true, lastScrollPos: currScrollPos});
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll.bind(this));
    }, []);

   ...
   }
```

**So my question is how do I update my state properties with react hooks in this example accordingly?**

Comment: I can't understand why you used setNavState instead of setState

Comment: @Skyentao, he is using functional component, not class component. he can't use setState inside functional component

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it's because how closure works. See, on initial render you're declaring `handleScroll` that has access to initial `navState` and `setNavState` through closure. Then you're subscribing for scroll with this #1 version of `handleScroll`.

Next render your code creates version #2 of `handleScroll` that points onto up to date `navState` through closure. But you never use that version for handling scroll.

See, actually it's not your handler "did not update state" but rather it updated it with outdated value.

## Option 1

Re-subscribing on each render

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
});
```

## Option 2

Utilizing `useCallback` to re-create handler only when data is changed and re-subscribe only if callback has been recreated

```
const handleScroll = useCallback(() => { ... }, [navState]);
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
}, [handleScroll]);
```

Looks slightly more efficient but more messy/less readable. So I'd prefer first option.

You may wonder why I include `navState` into dependencies but not `setNavState`. The reason is - setter(callback returned from `useState`) [is guaranteed](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) to be referentially same on each render.

[UPD] forgot about functional version of setter. It will definitely work fine while we don't want to refer data from another `useState`. So don't miss up-voting [answer by giorgim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57944861/2071697)

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem could be that you registered that listener once (e.g. like `componendDidMount`), now every time that listener function gets called due to scroll, you are referring to the same value of `navState` because of the closure.

Putting this in your listener function instead, should give you access to current state:

```
setNavState(ps => {
      if (currScrollPos > ps.lastScrollPos) {
        return { showNavLogo: false, lastScrollPos: currScrollPos };
      } else {
        return { showNavLogo: true, lastScrollPos: currScrollPos };
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add dependency and cleanup for useEffect

```js
function TabBar() {
    const [navState, setNavState] = React.useState(
        {
            showNavLogo: true,
            lastScrollPos: 0
        });

    function handleScroll(e) {
        const currScrollPos = e.path[1].scrollY;
        const { lastScrollPos, showNavLogo } = navState;

        console.log('showNavLogo: ', showNavLogo);
        console.log('lastScrollPos: ', lastScrollPos);
        if (currScrollPos > lastScrollPos) {
            setNavState({showNavLogo: false, lastScrollPos: currScrollPos});
        } else {
            setNavState({showNavLogo: true, lastScrollPos: currScrollPos});
        }
    }

    React.useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll.bind(this));
        
        return () => {
          window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll.bind(this));
        }
    }, [navState]);

     return (<h1>scroll example</h1>)
   }
   
   ReactDOM.render(<TabBar />, document.body)
```

```css
h1 {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @giorgim `navState` is constructed from literal object only on initial render. So then it will be changed only after `setNavState` is called